# How can I merge two lists column-wise leaving a blank space in between, for windows?

Tags: windows-10

How can I merge two lists column-wise in windows leaving a blank space between both?
This option merges two files but without leaving a blank space between both,

```
powershell $f1=gc File1.txt;$f2=gc File2.txt;for($i=0;$i-lt$f1.length;$i++){$f1[$i]+$f2[$i]}>Output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your currnet code, formatted for clarity, is:

```
$f1 = gc File1.txt
$f2 = gc File2.txt
for( $i=0 ; $i -lt $f1.length ; $i++ ){
    $f1[$i] + $f2[$i]
} > Output.txt
```

with the line `$f1[$i] + $f2[$i]` creating each list item (without the desired spacde).

**PowerShell** offers a variety of methods for string manipulation. Any of the follwoing would work to insert a space between the two items:

- Concatenation:

  - `$f1[$i] + ' ' + $f2[$i]`
- [Expandable String](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2#double-quoted-strings) with [subexpressions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#subexpression-operator--) :

  - `"$($f1[$i]) $($f2[$i])"`
- [-Join Operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join?view=powershell-7.2):

  - `$f1[$i], $f2[$i] -join ' '`
- [-f Format Operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#format-operator--f):

  - `'{0} {1}' -f $f1[$i], $f2[$i]`